# Why do the density operators span the whole operator space $\mathcal{B}(H)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, linear-algebra, density-operator

The convex set of density operators on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ defined by
$$\mathcal{D}(H):=\{\rho\in\mathcal{B}(H)\,|\,\rho\geq 0,\, \operatorname{tr}\rho =1\},$$
This set is said to span the entire space of operators $\mathcal{B}(H)$. Why is that so?

I guess there is an easy explanation, I just do not see it.

Comment: "is said to" -- who says that?

Comment: For instance Mark Wilde in his book Quantum Information Theory on page 745: http://www.markwilde.com/qit-notes.pdf

Comment: More precisely, on pages 150 and 745. But I have also seen it in other papers/books. In my understanding, the (complex) span of the set of density operators equals the full space of linear operators. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hello @quantumorsch , do you consider the given answer to be helpful enough for you? According to your formulation of the question it is not complete, but it "spans the complete answer" $\ddot\smile$. So there's room for expansion left, upon request.

Comment: Just as a comment, I find very misleading to formulate a result in the language of general operators despite it being true only for a finite dimensional Hilbert space (i.e., for matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that given an arbitrary matrix $A$, we can write $A$ as a linear combination of positive, unit-trace matrices.

To do this, you start by writing $A$ in terms of its Hermitian and skew-Hermitian components (see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2421948/173147) about this decomposition):
$$A=\underbrace{\frac{A+A^\dagger}{2}}_{\equiv A_1}+i\underbrace{\frac{A-A^\dagger}{2i}}_{
\equiv A_2}\equiv A_1+i A_2,$$
where $A_1,A_2$ are Hermitian (one can also easily show that this decomposition is unique).

Then, one can use the fact that for any Hermitian matrix $H$, there are positive matrices $H_+$ and $H_-$ such that $H=H_+-H_-$. An easy way to construct these is by having $H_+$ contain only the terms of the spectral decomposition of $H$ corresponding to positive eigenvalues, and similarly for $H_-$. Equivalently, we just define $H_+\equiv (H+|H|)/2$ and $H_-\equiv (|H|-H)/2$.

In conclusion, we managed to write
$$A=\frac{1}{2}[(A_{1,+}-A_{1,-})+i(A_{2,+}-A_{2,-})],$$
which tells you that any operator is a linear combination of *positive* ones. To show that it is also a linear combination of positive, *unit-trace* ones, you simply need to rescale each element in the sum to get operators with unit trace. For example, $A_{1,+}$ might not have unit-trace, but $A_{1,+}=\lambda(A_{1,+}/\lambda)$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, and we can choose $\lambda$ such that $\operatorname{tr}(A_{1,+}/\lambda)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your favourite operator $\,x\in\mathcal{B}(H)\,$ and write it as $\,x=a+ib\,$ where both
$$a={x+x^*\over 2}\quad\text{and}\quad b={x-x^*\over 2i}$$
are self-adjoint (or 'hermitian', synonymously). Here $x^*$ denotes the adjoint of $\,x$; it corresponds to *transposition and complex conjugation* if $\,x\,$ is represented as a matrix.
The linear combinations $\,a,b\,$ generalise the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

To get the desired conclusion note that the subset of self-adjoint operators 
in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ equals the $\mathbb{R}$-linear span of $\,\mathcal{D}(H)\,$.

Comment: That's only half the story - you also need to split a and b in their positive and negative part.

Comment: Then why didn't you just write "B(H) equals the C-linear span of D(H)"??

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I'd say the story is almost complete, and what you describe might be achieved by the OP himself, cf  his last sentence. Let's wait for quantumschorsch and his reaction ...